# IBM Worklight - Unable to display data retrieved using SQL adapter

Tags: javascript, sql, database, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to fetch data from a database and display it in the app.
Below is my code. The invokation is doing well, but the data is not displayed.

**sqlAdapter-impl.js**

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from studentinfo");

function getStudentInfos() {    
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

**sqlAdapter.js**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;

function wlCommonInit() {
    GetEmployeeData();
}

function GetEmployeeData() {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'sqlAdapter',
        procedure : 'getStudentInfos'
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadFeedsSuccess,
        onFailure : loadFeedsFailure
    });
}

function loadFeedsSuccess(result){
    WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");
    busyIndicator.hide();
    if (result.invocationResult.Items.length>0) 
        displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.Items);
    else 
        loadFeedsFailure();
}

function displayFeeds(items){
    var ul = $('#itemsList');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].sid);
        var pubDate = $('<div/>', {'class': 'pubDate'}).html(items[i].sname);
        li.append(pubDate);     
        ul.append(li);
    }
}
```

**sqlAdapter.html**

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <div id="itemsList"></div>

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sqlAdapter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

this is what I get on invoking the procedure

```
    {
    "isSuccessful": true,
    "resultSet": [
    {
     "sclass": "PUC",
     "sgrade": "A+",
     "sid": "PUC001",
     "sname": "Rohan"
     },
     {
     "sclass": "PUC",
     "sgrade": "A",
     "sid": "PUC002",
     "sname": "Rakesh"
     },
    {
     "sclass": "PUC",
     "sgrade": "C",
     "sid": "PUC003",
     "sname": "Raj"
     },
     {
     "sclass": "PUC",
     "sgrade": "E",
     "sid": "PUC004",
     "sname": "Roman"
      }
      ] 
      }
```

I just want all these things to be printed on the screen

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: i don't get anything on the console.

Comment: When you say 'on invoking the procedure it is doing well' do you mean that you do get data back from the procedure in the 'loadFeedSuccess'?

Comment: I think he means the invocation succeeds but displaying the items fails.

Comment: @user3465606, what is the result of the invocation? add it to the question.

Comment: I've added the result of procedure invocation in the question

Comment: Preview the app in Worklight Console in Chrome browser; open the dev tools. Do you see any errors?

Comment: No, I don't get any error, Its just that the screen is blank

Comment: Did you look in the Chrome Dev Tools? There should be SOMETHING there. Look at the Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change "Items":

```
if (result.invocationResult.Items.length>0) 
        displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.Items);
```

To "resultSet":

```
if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length>0) 
        displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
```

Second, I've used the `worklight_training` database script Worklight provides in conjunction with your code snippets from the question. I've altered the `displayFeeds` function to this:

```
function displayFeeds(items) {
    var ul = $('#itemsList'), i, li;

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {     
        // Create new <li> element and populate it
        li = $('<li/>').text(item.firstName);   
        // Append the <li> element to the <ul> element
        ul.append(li);      
    }
}
```

The end result was displaying the `firstName` values from the `users` table.
You can then play with your JavaScript a bit more to display what *you* want from **your** database table...

[image]

BTW, as you can see... the console in Chrome Dev Tools *does show something*... which you claim in your case it does not. You need to figure that out.

Comment: @user3465606, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.