# Return an array of resultSets from the server in worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I want to use the values from multiple rows returned in a resultSet to invoke a procedure again and again and display the result of the invoked procedure on main html page

Adapter JS

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from medicine WHERE Name= ? ");
var selectStatement2 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select LocId from location WHERE LocName= ? ");
var selectStatement3 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select RegNo from storeloc WHERE LocId= ? ");
var selectStatement4 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select RegNo from stormedavl where RegNo=? AND (MedId=? AND Availability=true)");
var selectStatement5 = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from store WHERE RegNo= ? ");



function getMedicineDetails1(Name,Location) { 
var a=getMedicineDetails(Name);
var MedId=a.resultSet;
var b=getLocId(Location);
var LocId=b.resultSet;
var c=getRegNo(LocId[0].LocId);
var cc=c.resultSet;
 //here c.resultSet contains two rows 
 var d={},e;
 if(cc && cc.length>0)
 {
    for(var i=0;i<c.resultSet.length;i++)
        {
            d[i]=getFinal(cc[i].RegNo,MedId[0].MedId);


        }
    return d;


}

}
function getMedicineDetails(Name) {    

   return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement,
        parameters : [Name]
    });
}
function getLocId(Location) {  
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement2,
        parameters : [Location]
    });
} 
    function getRegNo(LocId) {  
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement3,
        parameters : [LocId]
    });   



}
    function getFinal(RegNo,MedId) {    
           return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement4,
            parameters : [RegNo,MedId]
        });
    }

    function getStoreDetails(RegNo) {  
        return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : selectStatement5,
            parameters : [RegNo]
        });   



    }
```

JS file

```
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
 function wlCommonInit() {

 }
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#search").click(function(){
GetEmployeeData();

});



 });

 var med;

 function GetEmployeeData() {

var medicine= $("#medicine").val();
var location=$("#location").val();
alert(medicine);

var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'ATM',
    procedure : 'getMedicineDetails1',
    parameters: [medicine,location]
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
    onSuccess : loadFeedsSuccess,
    onFailure : loadFeedsFailure
});



 }
 function loadFeedsSuccess(result){

  alert("Hii");
 WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");

if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length>0) 
{

    displayFeeds2(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
}
else 
    loadFeedsFailure();

 }

  function loadFeedsFailure(result){


alert("Values Not Found in DB");
 }
  function displayFeeds2(items){
alert("ii");
var table = document.getElementById("myTable1");
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
    {
    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);

    // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the    "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = items[i].RegNo;
    }

    }
  function LoadResultPage()
  {
  $("AppDiv").hide();

  $("#itemsList").show();
  };
```

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>ATM</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ATM.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
    <div id="AppDiv">   
<h1> <img border="0" src="images/atm.png" width="50" height="50" align="middle">
<font color='white'> ANY TIME MEDICINE </font> 
</h1>
<br>
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="header">search medicine
    </div><br>

        <hr>
        <div data-role="content">       
        <input type="text" value="MEDICINE" id="medicine"><hr>
        <input type="text" value="LOCATION" id="location"><hr>
        <input type="submit" id="search" value="SEARCH">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="itemsList" data-role="page">

<table id="myTable1" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Registration No</th>
</tr>
</table>
    <div data-role="header">gg
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
</div>

 <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
 <script src="js/ATM.js"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js"></script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that at the output we get only one RegNo(registration no )instead of two as a result of calling getFinal adapter procedure from the loop.I want to ask the way we can store the result of invocations of getFinal procedure and then displat them at the html page.Basically i want to ask if we can return an array of resultSets from server to he client.

Comment: Just an idea, but shouldn't you unwrap the result of getFinal(cc[i].RegNo,MedId[0].MedId) before assigning it to d[i]?

Comment: to the client we need to return a resultset then how will we do that thing if we unwrap it and then store

Comment: Return a single resultSet containing an array of unwrapped results.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i do that through the code because i am unable to figureout how will i unwrap the results JSON.parse????

Comment: If you meant to say JSON.parse then i am getting the error "ERROR in generation of JSONFeed

Comment: Just to be clear you understand, that in cc you actually have an array of resultSets

Comment: @user3476186, see the Answer by Raanan. If it solves your problem, please set as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to mashup both result sets from the getRegNo with the getFinal.
Here is how to get an array of resultSets from the server

Change your code from:

```
//here c.resultSet contains two rows 
var d={},e;
if(cc && cc.length>0) {
    for(var i=0;i<c.resultSet.length;i++) {
        d[i]=getFinal(cc[i].RegNo,MedId[0].MedId);
    }
    return d;
}
```

in your code you will get something like `{0 : 'regNo_1', 1 : 'regNo_2'}` where the integer is `d[i]`

to:

```
    //here c.resultSet contains two rows
    if (cc && cc.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
            cc[i].regNo = getFinal(cc[i].RegNo,MedId[0].MedId);
        }
        return {'regNos' : cc};
    }
}
```

In order to get an array of resultSets that will look like this:

```
{
   "regNos": [
      {
         "regNo": 12345,
         "regNo": {
            "isSuccessful": true,
            "regNo": [
               {
                  "regNo": "1"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "regNo": 54321,
         "regNo": {
            "isSuccessful": true,
            "resultSet": [
               {
                  "regNo": "2"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true
}
```